# Extremely high CPU load in render loop

Tags: c#, rendering, render, directx-11, sharpdx

I am still working on my video game and my own game engine and I make a good progress. This weekend, I wanted to take some time to improve the performance of my game and to check for any memory leaks and so on. While most things look fine, I have an incredible high CPU load of around 45% (on an Intel i5 with four cores). First, I thought I had some very bad design in one of my modules, but even after removing all parts from the render process I still had a CPU load of around 40%!

This was my render loop after removing all my modules' render calls:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        _logger.BeginFunction(this.ToString(), "Run");

        RenderLoop.Run(Form, () =>
        {
            _deviceContext.ClearDepthStencilView(_depthView, SharpDX.Direct3D11.DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
            _deviceContext.ClearRenderTargetView(_renderTargetView, Color.Black);

            _swapChain.Present(0, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);
        });

        OnApplicationClosing();

        _logger.EndFunction();
    }
```

So, as you can see almost nothing happens and I still got that 40% CPU load. I checked, if anything is running in the background by printing the current stack trace every 5 seconds. Nothing was running in this process, after I disabled all my game engine's modules.

Then I remembered I had a similar issue many years ago during my studies, when a calculation thread was in an endless loop. Since the loop was not slowed down, it was executed as fast as possible which caused a high CPU load. Remembering this, I added an ugly line at the end of my render loop above:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Et voilà, my CPU load goes down to around 10%, even with all my game engine's modules activated.

However, this is not an acceptable final solution for my game engine. I took some time looking online for SharpDX render loop examples, but I was not able to figure out how other people handle this problem.

Is there any way to avoid the high CPU load without slowing the render loop down with a *thread sleep*?

I'd appreciate any hints and help from you! :-)

Comment: Unless you are using some technique for limiting fps, you are going to have 100% CPU and maximum fps possible. See e.g. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68126 or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51545.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace:

`_swapChain.Present(0, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);`

by

`_swapChain.Present(1, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);`

As stated in MSDN [Swapchain:Present](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174576(v=vs.85).aspx) doc:

- 0 - The presentation occurs immediately, there is no synchronization.
- 1 through 4 - Synchronize presentation after the nth vertical blank.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I looked up the samples from yesterday and they had this parameter set to one or two. I missed this detail :-/